# Flow - Lookup component for object two relationships away

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup, lightning-flow-builder

I have been trying to add a lookup component for a child object that is related to the child object of the parent. For example.

Object A is the object of the record that started the flow

Object B is the junction object

Object C is the object of the lookup I am trying to populate. Object C is related to Object B via a lookup field where Object C is the child and Object B is the parent

I need to add a lookup component that allows the user to access the lookup field for Object B and C, but I am receiving the following error:

[image]

My inputs are:

Field API Name: Id of Object A
Object API Name: Object A.Object B.Field__c

Comment: Please edit your question to include more specifics (without revealing anything sensitive) about how your Flow is currently set up: the inner details of the Flow element on which this error occurs; any upstream Get Records elements that are related; etc. Screen shots are helpful more often than not.

Comment: If Object B is a child object, how is Object A.Object B.Field__c going to work?  That's the dot notation where Object B is the parent of Object A.

Comment: Sorry, tried not to give away any confidential details. 

Yeah so the flow is launching on a record of Object A. We need to populate a field from Object B as a lookup and that lookup field on Object B is a lookup to Object C.

Comment: I understand confidentiality, but not seeing exactly how you have things set up/configured makes it really hard to help. You can take screenshots and edit them to cover up the proprietary/confidential words and leave the rest visible. You can do this in MS _Paint_ or MS _Snip & Sketch_ (you can edit directly on the snip). You could do it in GIMP (overkill) or other free programs. Or in a sandbox or Trailhead org you could create a few Custom Objects with generic names but with the same relationships as your real ones, create a test Flow and mock up the elements in it exactly like you have.